# Rails form helper checkbox always checked even when {checked: false}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

Ruby on Rails 4.2.1
In a view I'm making checkboxes like this:

```
<%= check_box_tag('roles[' + role.name + '][' + perm.name + ']', 1, {checked: role.permissions.include?(perm)}) %>
```

But this renders a checked checkbox every time, even when `role.permissions.include?(perm)` returns `false`

I've put `debugger` in the view and double checked this. inside the view when I put into the debug console this:

```
check_box_tag('test', 1, {checked: false})
```

Out comes this:

```
"<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"test\" id=\"test\" value=\"1\" checked=\"checked\" />"
```

Is this a bug in Rails form helpers or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [`check_box_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag) like:

```
check_box_tag('test', 1, false, {})
```

Read documentation:

```
 check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})
```

Third argument should be a boolean but you pass a hash that always return `true`.